# Incremental field in visual studio project properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What does the field incremental linking mean in the property pages of a project in visual studio?
What should it have in release and what in debug?
I found in the project that i am workin on that it is incremental in debug and incremental:no in release, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incremental linking allows the linker to modify the existing linked dll/exe instead of recreating it from scratch whenever something's changed and you build. Enabling it allows edit-and-continue to work - but in my experience it's not 100% reliable, so I'd recommend that you avoid it at least in release.

Answer (score 2):

Incremental linking adds extra padding between the linked modules, so that small changes can be added without relinking the entire file. Might improve relinking time in debug mode (unless the change is "to large").

Not very useful in release mode.